# driver.get not working in Selenium Webdriver, Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, steam

When using `driver.get` on a certain website (`driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730")`), I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking fireEvent
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'daltonpc', ip: '10.0.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:504)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.example.FinderClass.findOtherWeapon(FinderClass.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.example.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking fireEvent
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:612)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1001)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:748)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:920)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:925)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1298)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:290)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:475)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:491)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking fireEvent
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: illegal radix 0. (http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/shared_global.js?v=BESEFoKTgss6&l=english#1358)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:612)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1001)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:814)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:748)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventNode.fireEvent(EventNode.java:396)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:120)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegal radix 0. (http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/shared_global.js?v=BESEFoKTgss6&l=english#1358)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.runtimeError(StrictErrorReporter.java:81)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:1047)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError(Context.java:1094)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.reportRuntimeError1(Context.java:1062)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.numberToString(ScriptRuntime.java:813)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeNumber.execIdCall(NativeNumber.java:129)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:89)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 47 more
```

It works fine with other urls, and it also worked with this one until I enabled javascript by putting `true` in `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);`.  I needed to do this because my program wasn't working properly without javascript, and it seems like this steam community market page requires javascript in order to access it, even by just typing in the url.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but try using something like PhantomJSdriver, I have found that to be quite stable as compared to Htmluntidriver.

Comment: you need to mention which browser you want to simulate. So when you initialize driver, just add `HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);`  FYI: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html

Answer (score 2):

Using a user agent will solve the `ScriptException`. Use `DesiredCapabilties` to do so. See below code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setBrowserName("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20160101 Firefox/66.0");

HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

This works fine.

Although, an alternate solution would be to use `PhantomJSDriver` which I found to be much better at locating elements.

Download [PhantomJS.exe](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) file and set the exe's file path as `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY`

```
public class CopyOfTest1 
{
PhantomJSDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

CopyOfTest1()
{
    //set binary path of phantomJS driver
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();       
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "drivers/phantomjs.exe");
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
    capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0");

    //intialize driver and set capabilties
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
    //intitlaize webdriverwait class
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
}

void start()
{
    driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    driver.quit();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    new CopyOfTest1().start();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the "exception invoking fireEvent" error after including this code.  If I try a different url, however (http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p1_price_asc), I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "type" from null (http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js?v=.isFTSRckeNhC#2)`

Comment: This code worked for me. I would suggest you try using PhantomJSDriver. Its more stable.

Comment: I tried PhantomJSDriver, and it's giving me even more problems than before!  It's completely inconsistent for some reason, meaning if I run the program multiple times without changing the code, I get different results every time!  And the phantomjs task won't exit ever, even with `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`, I have to end the process manually with task manager.  If you know any way to fix this, do tell.

Comment: I have given you a small sample code for PhantomJSDriver that I had. Download phantomjs.exe file and set its file path for `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY`. For ex, I have this file in my project's folder - `"drivers/phantomjs.exe"`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  But it's still being very weird.  Sometimes when I run it it will fail to find a certain element, but other times that I run it it will find it just fine.  How is this happening without modifying any code?

Comment: All headless tests are like that only, try to use `presenceOfElementLocated`, you will have to do some trial and error with the locators to get the one that gives u same result consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotation **"** in url. Try the following

```
driver.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730")
```

Comment: That was just a copy and paste mistake on my part, It had quotes in my original code.